# I cannot install django-allauth inside virtual environment in a Django project?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, python-wheel

I am using a virtual environment inside a python project.I could easily install Django in it.Initially when I type 'pip freeze' command then this is the result -

```
Django==1.8
wheel==0.24.0
```

Now When I install django-allauth using pip then these errors throw up -

```
  File "/home/user/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 256, in link
self._link = self._wheel_cache.cached_wheel(link, self.name)
  File "/home/user/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 63, in cached_wheel
self._cache_dir, link, self._format_control, package_name)
  File "/home/user/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 124, in cached_wheel
wheel_names = os.listdir(root)
 OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/.cache/pip/wheels/8e/2c/02/5f7eb1a476cd75481801f52a0770262ed00573f48d830a4713'
```

I guess it has something to do with wheels package which came preinstalled when I created virtual environment but I dont know how to resolve it.

Comment: Did you effectively activate your environment?

Comment: @Filly - yes I activated the environment.Infact I installed Django in it too.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your wheel configuration is messed up and tries to write wheels into a directory you don't have access to. It might be the case that the django and wheel packages are already present in this directory, but allauth isn't.

You should probably try the `--no-use-wheel` option on `pip install`.